# How to print bounding box location in Object Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm using tensorflow and object detection api. I want to print bounding box location of object in test image. And this line show you vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array :

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      np.squeeze(boxes),
      np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
      np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=8)
```

I want to look inside 'boxes' because I guess 'boxes' maybe is store bounding box location. So, I convert 'boxes' to list but when I print it on cmd, it's too complex.

Any ideas for this ?

Comment: What framework are you using? Where is `vis_util` defined? What type of object is `boxes`? Are you trying to draw the boxes in tensorflow, or after processing? I think you'll get more responses if you add more detail to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the sollution.

1) After the line of code you quoted, write print(boxes).

2) It will return a [N,4] array, where N is the number of objects that was detected, so every row is a detected objected with a unique detection score.

3) Each row has 4 columns which represent normalized [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax] in the descending order of detection score, that is.

- The first row returns you the bounding box co-ordinates of the object that was detected with the highest score.
- The second row returns the bounding box co-ordinate of the object with the second highest score and so on.

4) To get the exact co-ordinate, multiply xmax and xmin with the upper limit of the x axis of your image and multiply ymax and ymin with the same of y axis.